# keeping prompt centered while working interactively

Tags: ipython, spyder

Doing interactive computing using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) in a terminal or as part of an IDE like [Spyder](http://spyder-ide.org/), it would be nice to maintain the prompt in the center of the screen.  Here is what typically happens:

1. Upon starting, the prompt (e.g. `In [1]:`) is at the top of the screen
2. A few interactive steps later, the prompt is at the bottom of the screen.
3. You type `clear` and are back at the top.

Is there any way to maintain the prompt in the center of the screen?  A smooth automatic scroll of the screen upwards so that the prompt stays centered would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) There's no way to maintain the prompt centered at the moment (September 2017), sorry.